# Generate a list of specified pauses

Tags: python, list

I've got 2 numbers:

```
amount = 100
seconds = 30000
```

I want to create a list of 100 `($amount)` pauses, that sum of them all is 30000 `($seconds)`.

And also the pauses have to be a number between 5 and 1000.

In other words, we have to divide 30000 into 100 random parts but between 5 and 1000.

How I do that?

Comment: You'll have to specify a distribution because there are (many) degree of freedom here. The random amounts can clump to the average or it could be flatter, entirely depending on what you want.

Comment: @RockyLi's question. but also, are the pauses strictly integer values, or are they decimal floats?

Comment: I want the numbers to be different from each other, there have to be 5 as well as 900 or 420. They are integers.

Comment: [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254301/algorithm-to-generate-n-random-numbers-between-a-and-b-which-sum-up-to-x) is relevant.

Comment: It would help me to have an example problem first, that we can solve in our heads easily, so I can see what you're looking for. Let's say `amount = 3`, `sum = 5`, and the values can be *anything greater than zero*. Also, I'm going to assume you only want integers, **please tell me** if this is incorrect. So for THIS problem, the possible outputs are `[(3, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 3)]`, 6 in total. So **if the distribution is uniform**, each outcome should have a equal probability of 1/6. Is this what you want?

Comment: 5, but yes, that exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Wookie... your question reads like homework from school and is considered a mechanical Turk question because its lacking some example code where you show effort. Showing effort is well appreciated on this site. Please update your question with something that show how it roughly should be. This also gives insight where things might go wrong too... Check CrepeGoats comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimal solution, more of a sketch since I'm pressed for time, but it seems to work:

First, make an array from 0 to `seconds`, like a timeline.

```
timeline = np.arange(0, seconds+1)
```

Now split it into equally spaced chunks of `min_length = 5`

```
chunks = []
for ii in range(0, seconds, 5):
    chunks.append(timeline[ii:ii+5])
```

Now, the idea is to choose a random element in `chunks`, merge the following 2 elements and then randomly split it into 2 chunks (thus reducing 3 chunks to 2). But we need to do it in a way such that we never split it into chunks with size less than `min_length=`5 but not greater than `max_length=1000`. We will then loop over this until we get to the desired number of chunks, i.e. `amount=100`

```
def random_merge(chunks, min_length, max_length):
    arr = chunks.copy() # just to be safe

    # Choose random point
    rand_idx = random.randint(0, len(arr)-3)

    # Combine merge with the following 2 elements
    arr[rand_idx] = np.append(arr[rand_idx], arr[rand_idx + 1])
    arr[rand_idx] = np.append(arr[rand_idx], arr.pop(rand_idx + 2))

    # choose a random length to split into smaller chunks such that neither
    # smaller chunk has a length less than min_length
    rand_split = random.randint(min_length, len(arr[rand_idx]) - min_length)
    arr[rand_idx+1] = arr[rand_idx][rand_split:]
    arr[rand_idx] = arr[rand_idx][:rand_split]

    # check to see if the split made an element with length greater than
    # max_length if not return your new smaller array, if not just return the
    # original array and start over
    if len(arr[rand_idx] < max_length) and len(arr[rand_idx+1] < max_length):
        return arr
    else:
        return chunks
```

Now, just loop over until you reach the desired number of chunks:

```
while len(chunks) > amount:
    chunks = random_merge(chunks)
```

This will give you the partitioned timeline, to get to durations, just measure their lengths

```
pauses = [len(xx) for xx in chunks]
```

EDIT: Note, this will tend to cause all intervals to become roughly equal since you are choosing uniformly. I think you can just change the way you sample `rand_idx` to something like a gaussian centered in the middle of the timeline. Then you can shuffle the pauses so that the short ones aren't always at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way would be to start with a uniform distribution and then randomly pick two indices and move a random amount, capped by the min and max values, from one to the other. Do this a certain number of times, and the sequence should be sufficiently random while preserving all the constraints.

```
from random import randint, randrange
n, k = 30000, 100
mn, mx = 5, 1000
nums = [n//k for _ in range(k)]

for _ in range(10000):
    a, b = randrange(k), randrange(k)
    swap = randint(0, min(mx - nums[a], nums[b] - mn))
    nums[a] += swap
    nums[b] -= swap

print(min(nums), max(nums), sum(nums))
# 5 1000 30000
print(nums)
# [9, 773, 65, 812, 23, 124, 396, 406, 51, 241, 241, 841, 274, 210, 28, 213, 550, 131, 243, 974, 194, 927, 174, 910, 121, 230, 22, 7, 22, 128, 404, 247, 276, 8, 118, 68, 5, 216, 45, 10, 43, 32, 723, 56, 398, 12, 861, 625, 200, 755, 6, 563, 77, 279, 424, 6, 523, 15, 540, 858, 925, 491, 21, 499, 984, 21, 397, 18, 219, 83, 5, 171, 588, 159, 126, 796, 5, 68, 62, 12, 169, 849, 96, 426, 637, 127, 44, 497, 237, 597, 447, 19, 12, 267, 85, 78, 112, 471, 447, 1000]
```

For simplicity, this assumes that `n` is evenly divisible by `k`, but even if it's not, that first step would be easy to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't put my effort in the question, because I had some idea but wanted to see totally different view on the problem.
After your answers I reconsidered my plan and wrote this:

```
import random

amount = 100
seconds = 30000

numbers = list(range(0,1001))
print(numbers)

pauses = []
i=0
while i < amount:
    rand_idx = random.randint(0, len(numbers)-1)
    pauses.append(numbers[rand_idx])
    i+=1

pausetime = sum(pauses)


if pausetime > seconds:
    while pausetime > seconds:
        max_idx = pauses.index(max(pauses))      # check index of highest pause
        half_rand_idx = random.randint(0, (len(numbers)-1)/2)
        pauses[max_idx] = numbers[half_rand_idx] # change highest pause for other random pause from first half
        pausetime = sum(pauses)          # check the sum of all pauses

elif pausetime < seconds:
    while pausetime < seconds:
        max_idx = pauses.index(min(pauses)) # check index of lowest pause
        pauses[min_idx] = numbers[rand_idx] # change highest pause for other random pause
        pausetime = sum(pauses)         # check the sum of all pauses

else:
    pass

print(pauses)
print(pausetime)
```

it actually leaves us with pausetime a little bit less than $seconds, but for my case it's perfect.